# Merging pandas on datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes like the following:

```
date                B
2017-01-03 01:00    0.017
2017-01-04 02:55    0.024
2017-01-05 16:53    -0.01
2017-01-06 10:22    0.024



date                A
2017-01-03 01:00    0.018
2017-01-06 09:16    -0.02
```

I would need to transform then to a one dataframe like that:

```
date                A       B
2017-01-03 01:00    0.018   0.017
2017-01-04 02:55            0.024
2017-01-05 16:53            -0.01
2017-01-06 09:16    -0.02
2017-01-06 10:22            0.024
```

How can I get it?

Comment: `df1.merge(df2,on='date')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**naming `df2` as the dataframe that contains column A, and `df1` as the dataframe that contains column B**

Use [DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df2.merge(df1,on='date',how='outer',sort=True)
```

Output:

```
             date      A      B
0 2017-01-03 01:00:00  0.018  0.017
1 2017-01-04 02:55:00    NaN  0.024
2 2017-01-05 16:53:00    NaN -0.010
3 2017-01-06 09:16:00 -0.020    NaN
4 2017-01-06 10:22:00    NaN  0.024
```